Microcharts.Maui, ChartView item is invisible and unable to set HeightRequest or WidthRequest parameters
I'm building an application using the MAUI framework in Visual Studio 2022 and I wanted to add a plot to my app using the Microcharts.Maui package.
I've successfully installed the package and there doesn't appear to be any issues in my .csproj or MauiProgram.cs files, as far as I can tell, I've installed the package correctly. However, when I try to add a ChartView object to my app and add data to it, I cannot see the resulting plot.
I've attempted to set the HeightRequest and WidthRequest parameters for the item, but when I do so, I encounter the following warning:

"A debugger is attached to [app name].exe but not configured to debug the unhandled exception. To debug this exception, detach the current debugger."

Here's some code snippets for context:
XAML containing ChartView
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:micro="clr-namespace:Microcharts.Maui;assembly=Microcharts.Maui"
             x:Class="Finance_Manager_Mobile.Windows.ProfileView"
             Title="ProfileView">

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout>
            <micro:ChartView BackgroundColor="Black" x:Name="plotCanvas" IsVisible="True" 
                             VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                             HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" />

        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    
</ContentPage>

C# code behind for ChartView
using Microcharts;

namespace Finance_Manager_Mobile.Windows;

// This page is the view of an open profile
public partial class ProfileView : ContentPage
{
    public ProfileView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ChartEntry[] entries = new ChartEntry[]
        {
            new ChartEntry(100), new ChartEntry(200), new ChartEntry(300)
        };
        plotCanvas.Chart = new LineChart
        {
            Entries = entries
        };
    }

I've tried uninstalling and re-installing the package, but the issue persists.
Interestingly, if I set either the HeightRequest or WidthRequest in the XAML, it doesn't work, but if I set either of them in the  code behind, it does work. However, it only seems to work if I set one or the other, it still results in a warning if I try to set both of them.

Did you try a bigger height and width like 700? And is the background color visible if you set it for the chart or the stacklayout?

@Tobination, so I've just tried some things and if I set the BackgroundColor for the VerticalStackLayout then it's visible but if I set it for the ChartView it's invisible. Also, very strangely, opening up the project again today, it seems that I can now set the HeightRequest parameter in the XAML code without triggering the warning... I didn't change anything! However, I still can't see the ChartView at all, but I know it's there because increasing the height effects the ScrollView it's wrapped in

Did you set the background property in the xaml.cs? Because you have to. And did you try a bigger height and width?

Also try to remove all Propertoes in xaml and only set the height to 700 and the name. Also remove the ScrollView.

@Tobination So, I hadn't tried setting the background colour in the xaml.cs, but I've just given it a try and it's still not showing. And I've set the HeightRequest to 700, but strangely today, it's gone back to producing the warning message and this time it's happening if I set it in either the .xaml or the xaml.cs file. Also, I've removed the ScrollView along with all unnecessary properties from the ChartView object for now but it still doesn't seem to be working

Ok. And your construtor gets called? I only used Microcharts with mvvm.

To use MicroChart in MAUI, in addition to installing Microcharts.Maui NuGet package, you also need to install SKiaSharp.Views.Maui.Controls.
After that, add .UseSKiaSharp() to the MauiProgram.cs file of the project:
var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
builder
    .UseMauiApp<App>()
    .UseSkiaSharp();


Fantastic, I've just installed the extra NuGet package, added the line to my MauiProgram.cs file and I'm finally seeing some data plotted! Thanks so much for your help!! I wonder why there wasn't any kind of warning that this package was needed too. Regardless, seems to be working now and I can adjust the HeightRequest without issue as well
